# Metal drainage grate, available off the shelf, or will need to have it custom made?

Tags: drainage

I need a metal drainage grate that will be at the foot of some stairs leading into a basement.

Is this something I will need to specially order or have fabricated, or can it be bought standard?

I did talk to a drainage grate company, but they said all their grates only come in 2 foot sections, so if I wanted a continuous 48" grate they would not have that.

Comment: We can not answer that if We do not know anything about the "foot of some stairs" !

Comment: Why couldn't you just place the 2 2 ft sections next to cover the 4 ft drain?

Comment: @PhilippNagel Because then there would be a seam in the grate and it would be lighter so when you stepped on it, it would clank. And its bad luck to step on cracks.

Comment: Add photo of the area, this would provide better details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could weld the sections together pretty easily. Or is it an aesthetic issue? You could also find lengths of either precast concrete, or plastic, trench drains in various lengths that include a grate. Wasn't sure if you need just the grate or the drain channel as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not find the exact size grate that you need "off the shelf" then **you will have to find alternative**.

Custom  made OR buy a bigger one and use an angle grinder to cut it to size. Go to steel/metal supplier, you can get grating material in a variety of sizes.

*This answer is as comprehensive as possible given the information provided in the question.*

Answer (score 1):

[McMaster-Carr has bar grates](https://www.mcmaster.com/drain-grating/bar-grating/) in stock sizes including 48", and custom sizes are available. I'm not affiliated with McMaster-Carr but I've used them as a source for industrial supplies for over 20 years.

Comment: That is interesting. For a stairwell, 48" is a feasible size.